# Ajax or Jquery loading until page is done rendering rails view page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Ok so what i want to do seems pretty simple, but i'm not very family with ajax or jQuery in my rails app i mostly use Javascript for things like this.

So what i want to do is basically hide the content of the page or grey it out while showing the loading icon until everything is done loading, how would i go about doing this ?

if it matters i'm using rails 3.2.13

The reason i want to do this is on some slower browsers/computers i see basically all the elements as they render which i think is quite annoying

Ooh and would it be possible to add a delay? that is even after the page has finished rendering still have the page contents for a specific number of seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a `style="z-index: 9999"` (or, better, a css rule setting said property) div covering the whole body of the page. Then you can go with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#imtheloadingdiv").fadeOut();
});
```

Or with waiting part (i.e. 3s timeout):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function()
  {
       $("#imtheloadingdiv").fadeOut();
  }, 3000);
});
```

(you can swap `fadeOut` for `hide` if you want to just make it disappear with no effects)

Comment: ooh Thanks that should be easy enough what about a loading gif or something of that sorts in the center of the page until timeout expires ? any ideas

Comment: just place the gif inside that #imtheloadingdiv div and it will be the only thing you can see on the page. For the effect to work you need to make it so the #imtheloadingdiv covers the whole page and set a background color for it or it will look bad!

Comment: ooh wait i just realized something .ready() is called only when the page has finished loading i want to hide it before it starts loading, is that possible ?

Comment: You hide everything by covering it with the div. The function actually hides the "cover" so it shows your content